# SwiftUI View flickering when displaying it based on State with if-else

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to display a certain form in the app based on a `Picker` selected value. However, when I switch using the segmented control fast enough (here it seems forced, but when the form is more complex it's very noticeable). Edit: this seems to be happening with all `View`s, not just forms.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var calculationType = CalculationType.months
    
    @State private var balanceOwned: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Calculation Type", selection: $calculationType) {
                ForEach(CalculationType.allCases, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            // This check seems to be the cause of the problem!
            if calculationType == .months {
                CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
            } else if calculationType == .fixed {
                CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
            } else {
                CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomForm: View {
    
    @Binding var balanceOwned: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Test", text: $balanceOwned)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum CalculationType: String, CaseIterable {
    case months
    case fixed
    case minimum
}
```

Whatever is inside the form flickers. How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Nothing bad observed with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: Also nothing with Xcode 11 / iOS 13

Comment: Thanks! Have you switched between the first and second segmented control options fast? @Asperi

Comment: This might help you: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127218 and

Comment: @pawello2222 thanks, it's not the picker that jumps, it's the form. See gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing structural identity problem, when dealing with conditions,
If you want to reuse same CustomForm and data can be populated based on balanceOwned, then need to preserve identity.

Either you give explicit identity or refactor structure to preserve structural identity of SwiftUI view.

Explicit Identity:

```
var body: some View {
    ....
    Picker("Calculation Type", selection: $calculationType) {
        ForEach(CalculationType.allCases, id: \.self) {
            Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: calculationType, perform: pickerChange(_:))
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
 
    if calculationType == .months {
        CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
        .id("11") // Common hashable explicit identity used.
    } else if calculationType == .fixed {
        CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
        .id("11")
    } else {
        CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned)
        .id("11")
    }
    ...
}
```

Structural Identity:

```
var body: some View {
    ...
    Picker("Calculation Type", selection: $calculationType) {
        ForEach(CalculationType.allCases, id: \.self) {
            Text($0.rawValue.capitalized)
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: calculationType, perform: pickerChange(_:))
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

    CustomForm(balanceOwned: $balanceOwned) // Preserve structural identity
    ...
}

func pickerChange(_ type: CalculationType) {
    switch type {
    case .months:
        balanceOwned = "Months"
    case .fixed:
        balanceOwned = "Fixed"
    case .minimum:
        balanceOwned = "Minimum"
    }
}
```